# How to work with Oracle, .Net, Winform, Windows Vista and XP

Tags: .net, winforms, oracle, windows-vista, windows-xp

I have an application that is a WinForm in C# that work with Oracle as database.

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2008 in Vista, with Vista Oracle Client (10.2.0) and ODP.Net (2.102.2.20).

The problem is that some users od this application work with Windows XP, so the Client isn't the same and the application says that it's "need" the correct client version in order to work.

I've tried to search information about this but seems that anybody is developing for desktop using Oracle as Database...

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: If my answer is completely off the mark and you have to use Oracle 10 Client, could you post the specific error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a particular requirement that you use Oracle Client 10.2.0, I would recommend you use Oracle Client 11.  The 11 Client is compatible with 10g, and 11g servers (and maybe 9i - don't remember offhand).

There's also the huge advantage that you don't need to use the Oracle Universal Installer, but instead can just run a batch file supplied by Oracle to do the necessary installation and uninstallation.

However, the instant client may not work for you as a developer because it does not include tools like SqlPlus or sqlldr.

You can download Oracle 11 Client with Xcopy Deploy [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/htdocs/distlic.html?url=/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/utilsoft.html).